# How to make sign out from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

This is the code I am using for firebase sign in. After completing the verification I am signing out. But when I try to sign in again with the same number it doesn't send me otp.

Help me to signout from it.
Thanks in advance.
This is the code:

```
 @Override
public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
 // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
 // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
 //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
      // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
 //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
 //     user action.
// Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
    //mAuth.signOut();
     mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     if(mAuth!=null)
         mAuth.signOut();
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"verification complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

```
 @Override
 public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
 // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
 // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
 // by combining the code with a verification ID.
//   Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"code sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
 mVerificationId = verificationId;
 mResendToken = token;
mobileNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    otpButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     otpText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 }

 otpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId,otpText.getText().toString());
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    "+91"+mobileNumber.getText().toString(),// Phone number to verify
                    60,// Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,// Unit of timeout
                    MainActivity.this,// Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);
        }
    });
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
 mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"verification 
                 done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
        } else {
        if (task.getException() instanceof 
            FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"verification failed code 
                invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        }
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: otp ? what that suppose to mean ?

Comment: Post you sign in code, because for me your signout is fine and you have problems in sign in again thanks :)

Comment: actually this method runs when mobile OTP code is verified.

Comment: wait i am uploading.

Comment: (The first code block is followed by a dangling "}": fix your indenting.)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SMS authorisation uses logic with instantly verified phone numbers.

This is meant that when you run app on real device and ask for SMS:

- First time you get SMS.
- After you logout
- Then you ask for SMS again, and ..... you will not get it. You will get "verificationCompleted" callback because framework recognise the same SIM card and device and will not ask for SMS again.

Lets look to the method

```
  /// [verificationCompleted] This callback must be implemented.
  ///   It will trigger when an SMS is auto-retrieved or the phone number has
  ///   been instantly verified. The callback will receive an [AuthCredential]
  ///   that can be passed to [signInWithCredential] or [linkWithCredential].

  /// [codeSent] Optional callback.
  ///   It will trigger when an SMS has been sent to the users phone,
  ///   and will include a [verificationId] and [forceResendingToken].
  ///
  /// [codeAutoRetrievalTimeout] Optional callback.
  ///   It will trigger when SMS auto-retrieval times out and provide a
  ///   [verificationId].
  Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber({
    @required String phoneNumber,
    @required Duration timeout,
    int forceResendingToken,
    @required PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted,
    @required PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed,
    @required PhoneCodeSent codeSent,
    @required PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
  }
```

You can see that there is "[verificationCompleted] This callback must be implemented.".

So just add to your code this logic. For example:

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
          (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
        user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)).user;
        print('Phone number already checked.');
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I really want add with `awaik's` answer is,when your app is in developing stage google suggest not to use real number to get sms,it will affect your quota and cause you several restriction.Google provides using whitelist number when your app is in developing stage.What whitelist number give you the facilitates to complete the verification steps in a mimic way.To create a white list number go to your firebase console->go to authentication->select sign in method->phone signin.From there you can create a white list number or use the existing  one (white list number must be the number which usually not using in real world),also you have the option to setup a 6 digit's dummy OTP.I added an image which might help you[image]